# Can't update command line tools because Xcode tells me I don't have access to them

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 and it tried to install an update to the command line tools. 
I clicked the update button and Xcode told me that `[my apple id] does not have access to Command Line Tools. (Contact Apple Developer Support to resolve account access issues.)`

The problem happened with 4.3.1 too, I just did the update to 4.3.2 because I thought that it will resolve the issue.

My account is a paid Mac + iOS Developer account. I am pretty sure I should have access to these tools. But Xcode tells me I don't. 
I logged in to the developer portal and checked for new Terms of Service too. Everything looks alright.

How can I install the update? Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes its all over the Twitter... Just go to [Apple Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#) and manually install it. They are investigating the issue as far as I know

Comment: Apple downloads is down too. I'm seeing "No Records" on this page.

Comment: @alladinian: as of July 26, 2012 the page https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action has only Command Line tools for 10.7.x, which do not work in 10.8 and you can't get one unless you're enrolled into apple developers program ($99/year).

Comment: @earlyadopter Thanks for clarifying. I will try to edit the answer in order to make it absolutely clear that it was given in a very specific time-context.

Answer (score 2):

Dominik Porada details the solution at [Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.1 Simulator](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator), ie. download the old XCode 4.4.1 from Apple and pull out the simulation. Personally, I just copied the simulator from one of my other Macs that I hadn't upgraded XCode on yet.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's still relevant but `xcode-select --install` might do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last night after the update to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4.

This morning I tried to build something in xcode and it told me that developer mode wasn't enabled on the mac. Once I enabled it, I tried to download the command tools again and that happened to work fine now.