# Unable to install iOS 5.1 Simulator in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I want to install iOS 5.1 Simulator in Xcode 4.5 then I receive a following error

[image: Error installing iOS 5.1 Simulator]

You can see I have installed iOS 5.0 Simulator without problems. Do you know how can I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819764/cant-update-command-line-tools-because-xcode-tells-me-i-dont-have-access-to-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action and download it manually.

I had same problem as you and I wasn't able to download Command Line Tools from XCode 4.5 with same error message you are getting. I noticed when I logged into Member Center on Apple Developer portal that I had some warning message which was saying that Apple has changed some License Agreement text. This License Agreement change should be accepted. Without that I wasn't even able to gain access to iOS 6 SDK beta part of iPhone Developer portal. After accepting this, I was able to download latest version of XCode 4.5 and do all updates from XCode (Command Line Tools and iOS 5.0 Simulator as well).

Comment: Thank you, after accepting the license agreement I could install the simulator from Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated OSX if possible and restarted XCode.

Answer (score 1):

While the issue is not fixed by apple you can find a temporary solution [here](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator)

Credit goes to [jesper-christensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514022/jesper-christensen/) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819764/cant-update-command-line-tools-because-xcode-tells-me-i-dont-have-access-to-th).

Cheers Jesper and Dominik